# HTTP authentication for Azure using AzurePowerTools from Devbridge

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I'm trying to temporarily secure a ASP.NET (the starter pack) site under construction hosted on Azure using:

https://github.com/devbridge/AzurePowerTools

More on:

http://www.devbridge.com/articles/basic-authentication-for-windows-azure-websites

If I run their test-project it works fine. But if I add the module I end up with redirect loops like this:

```
 http://localhost:53529/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FLogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FAccount%252FLogin%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252FAccount%25252FLogin%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252FAccount%2525252FLogin%2525253FReturnUrl%2525253D%252525252FAccount%252525252FLogin%252525253FReturnUrl%252525253D%25252525252FAccount%25252525252FLogin%25252525253FReturnUrl%25252525253D%2525252525252FAccount%2525252525252FLogin%2525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525253D%252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252FLogin%252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525253D%25252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525253D%2525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252F
```

Anyone with a clue?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your interest in our work.

It seems that your website is already using Forms authentication. I do not think that basic authentication is needed for your website.

Today I also tried and successfully added basic authentication to two websites that use Forms authentication. So our module should work with websites using forms authentication.

I suggest to use Fiddler and investigate the traffic between the server and browser. You can also download the source code from the GitHub and try to debug authentication module.

Comment: Any idea why it behaves like this? I'm using your package to make a project that I'm working on not visible on the web.

Comment: I think there might be another module or piece of code that intercepts response, clears everything from the response and sends redirect to login page. Do you get the authentication dialog in browser?

Comment: No it just ends up in a redirect loop to the login page that eventually fails.

Comment: Try disabling forms authentication and see if that helps. Maybe you have another custom module that intercepts response and sends user to login page. I think that there is some other piece of code that conflicts with basic authentication module. Basic authentication module is clearing response and sending authentication headers to browser. Then response is intercepted by other code that clears auth headers and sends redirect to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

The answer, while very hard to find, is actually simple.  Add these two lines to the appSettings section of the Web.config file:

```
<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
```

Now the Forms authentication will function as expected and redirect to the page you indicate in the Web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be happening is that the BasicAuthenticationModule from the AzurePowerTools package is sending an HTTP 401 Unauthorized response code which causes the FormsAuthenticationModule to redirect the browser to the login page, this causes the AzurePowerTools module to return another 401 status...you get the picture.

The easiest way to solve this, in theory, would be to remove the forms authentication module via a web.config change:

`<modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>`

> Reference: [Basic Authentication with WCF Web API hosted in IIS / Getting a 404 - Disable Forms Authentication Redirection](http://blog.alexonasp.net/post/2011/08/23/Basic-Authentication-with-WCF-Web-API-hosted-in-IIS-Getting-a-404-Disable-Forms-Authentication-Redirection.aspx)
>
> Even if it is disabled, ASP.NET Forms Authentication module intercepts our 401 from the Basic Authentication Handler and does the redirect.
>
> If you’re using IIS and the ASP.NET MVC Web Site just for the sake of hosting your Web API you’re almost done – just remove the ASP.NET Forms Authentication in your web.config: ...

Comment: But I need the FormsAuthentication for developing the website. The HttpAuthentication is only for temporarily making the website private.

Comment: You can re-enable the FormsAuthenticationModule whenever you want, you only have to remove the config change above; when you do that, make sure to also disable AzurePowerTools as it will interfere with forms authentication.